# TypeScript check instance class via user defined type guard

Tags: typescript

Well, I have implemented `isInstanceOfClass` function, so that it can tell if the instance is instance of given class, now I need to write correct typing for it.

```
class Parent {
    isInstanceOfClass<T>(arg: T): this is T {
        // already implemented
    }
}

class FooClass extends Parent {
    foo: number;
}

class BarClass extends Parent {
    bar: number;
}
```

Example:

```
let foo: Parent;
if(foo.isInstanceOfClass(FooClass)) {
    foo.foo = 1; // TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Parent & typeof FooClass'.
}
```

Can somebody help me get rid of the error?

For various reasons I can only change the `isInstanceOfClass` method signature, not the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there!
It should be:

```
class Parent {
    isInstanceOfClass<T>(arg: { new(): T }): this is T {
        // already implemented
    }
}
```

The difference is that what you're passing to `isInstanceOfClass` is not the instance but the class.
Once you change it to be the class (constructor) then the error goes away.

Comment: I always forgot the `{ new(): T }` thing!